Breaker trips with fan installation. What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to power up my ceiling fan, but for unknown reasons, it keeps tripping the breaker. I had it connected the same way in the other room, and it was working perfectly.
The fan is composed of the actual fan and a small electric box that came with the fan (I assume for the remote).
So I connected the black/hot wire (coming from the ceiling) to the black wire coming from the fan box, and the white neutral wire (coming from the ceiling) to the white wire from the fan box.
Then, I connected the green wire coming from the fan box to the yellow/green wire coming from the actual fan.
Finally, I connected two sets of clip-on wires in the purple circles that come from the fan and the fan box.
What am I doing wrong that it trips the breaker every time? Should I call an electrician?


Tripping the breaker usually means hot touching ground(metal).  Any chance you pinched the insulation on the hot?

What kind of breaker is it? If it is GFCI, AFCI, or dual-function it can trip for reasons other than a short circuit. If the breaker has a "TEST" button it is one of these kinds. In that case look to see whether it has a blinking LED to indicate the reason for tripping. Also, you could try disconnecting and capping the black wire coming from the ceiling. Does the breaker still trip in that case?

You were both right. The break still tripped after capping the black wire. I was pinching the black wire. Thanks so much.
